# Translating Modis HDF To GeoTIFF?

Tags: qgis, python, gdal

I've a MODIS04 L2, and I want to extract band
8:Image_Optical_Depth_Land_And_Ocean. I use Quantum GIS to open this band,
because Quantum GIS see this is not coordinates so this allow me to select
projection as below: +proj=utm +zone=50 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m
+no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0.

All I know is that I want to translate to WGS84. This open this band seems
good but when I open this band with ENVI this is better (differents output
images). But I see the Modis Conversion Toolkit use same warp parameters as
Quantum Gis expect it has a parameters ("Numbers of Warp Points").

I think that I miss something with QGIS and GDAL too.

This is Envi Conversion Toolkit

[image]

This is open file HDF with QGIS

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the [MODIS Reprojection Tool (MRT)](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/modis_reprojection_tool), which allows you to convert, reproject, and mosaic MODIS HDF files. Here's a screenshot:

[image: MODIS reprojection tool]

There's even a web-based version called [MRTWeb](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/get_data/mrtweb) so you don't have to download each of the individual HDF you want to process. Here's another screenshot:

[image: MRTWeb]

Comment: As of 2019, links to the Modis Reprojection Tool seem to return 404 errors. Instead, you can use HDF-EOS to GeoTiff Conversion Tool: https://newsroom.gsfc.nasa.gov/sdptoolkit/HEG/HEGDownload.html

Comment: As of May 2020, the link for HEG is https://wiki.earthdata.nasa.gov/display/DAS/HEG%3A++HDF-EOS+to+GeoTIFF+Conversion+Tool

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is simple but I just use the gdal translate function with -sds and convert them all to geotiff and it seems to work fine and is in WGS 1984 if I remember correctly.

http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html

For example

```
for %A in ("...\*.hdf") do gdal_translate -of GTiff -sds "%A" "%A.tiff"
```

Will convert all sub-datasets in HDF to Geotiff

Comment: For Windows, the line should be `for %%A in ("*.hdf") do gdal_translate -of GTiff -sds "%%A" "%%A.tiff"`. Unfortunately, SWATH data will not get proper CRS information.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add Chris' comment as answer. 
As stated, the MODIS Reprojection tool is no longer supported. 
NASA's HEG tool can convert from HDF to GeoTIFF: https://newsroom.gsfc.nasa.gov/sdptoolkit/HEG/HEGHome.html