# HDF5 files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, visualisation, hdf, hdf5

I am working with GPM GMI precipitation data that is stored in the hdf5 data format. All I am trying to do is import and visualize the data in the QGIS environment. I can import the precipitation file and it displays but is incorrect and skewed. I found a work around using [ArcGIS](http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/recipes/?q=recipes/How-to-Import-HDF5-formatted-IMERG-GPM-Precipitation-Data-into-ArcGIS)but have not been able to repeat this in QGIS. Does anyone know how I can visualize this precipitation data in QGIS?

Comment: related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65875/how-can-i-translate-modis-hdf-to-geotiff

Comment: These formats are incredibly general, you need more details and ideally a sample file. Explore it with GDAL directly which is what qgis uses

Comment: Another resource for hdf import: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183239/loading-osus-ocean-productivity-on-qgis. But every hdf provider stores the data a bit different.